# Laravel - auto count of input before submitting

Tags: php, laravel

Welcome again ! Can you please tell me how to count of 2 inputs and show it in third input before submitting?
For example i have :

inputa = value inserted by user

inputb = valueinserted by user

result = inputa + inputb ( counted and showed in inputc)

and then submit button to save it to database

Regards and thank you for help

Comment: so basic its  html form with inputa b and c and that input c is auto filled with value of inputa+ inputb and after autofilling of input C submit and save it to database

Comment: it can be only done via vue js? or i can do it somehow in php

Comment: Sounds like you need javascript if you want input c to be auto populated during the same request

Answer (score 0):

seems javascript / jquery fits your need.